# Python selenium send keys to driver

Tags: python, selenium

I am Software student.

I was messing around with selenium in python in chrome, and I'm trying to make a auto purchase bot. But one thing doesn't really want to work. I would like to hard refresh, and I was curious if there is a way to send a key combination <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + r</kbd> to the driver. How can we do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Be more specific about what combination do you want to send.

Comment: @bilakos control+shift+r to hard refresh in chrome

Comment: @Chris not really i used         actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('r').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform() but that didnt work.

Comment: You have 2 ways to do that. The first is to `refresh` the chrome from the Chrome driver. You have mentioned a variable like `driver` or `browser`. So go there and type `driver.refresh()` or `browser.refresh()` or the variable you have mentioned. The second method is by importing the module `keyboard`. Go to the `cmd` and type `pip install keyboard`  or by importing `puautogui` and you can install it like this `pip install pyautogui`. After that import it on the code you have wrote.

Comment: With `pyautogui` you can add this code `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'r')` and it will make your combination

Comment: @bilakos So i have i use browser.refresh() but its not a hard refresh and with something like keyboard its like a keypress on my hole computer, I want that only my driver gets a send_key so i can do other stuff while thats running in the back.

Comment: @Itz_Floris What do you mean by saying "hard refresh" ?

Comment: @bilakos so it clears my browser cache for the specific page

Comment: @Itz_Floris try this `browser.execute_script("location.reload(true);")`

Comment: it won't invalidate all cached contents it will invalidates only main page use driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.reload", {"ignoreCache": True}) devprotocol . Added it to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrl+shift+r is a browser level short cut you cannot trigger that from selenium.

### If you want to refresh by forcing the pages to be loaded from server and not cache use the devtool protocal:

First install Selenium 4 :

```
pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7
```

Selenium 4 supports `devtool` protocol now use below code:

```
 driver.get(
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190723/python-selenium-send-keys-to-driver")
 driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.reload", {"ignoreCache": True})
```

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-reload

> Page.reload # Reloads given page optionally ignoring the cache.
> PARAMETERS ignoreCache boolean If true, browser cache is ignored (as
> if the user pressed Shift+refresh). scriptToEvaluateOnLoad string If
> set, the script will be injected into all frames of the inspected page
> after reload. Argument will be ignored if reloading dataURL origin.

### **Updated on the Comment**

`location.reload(boolean)` is deprecated now and also:

**`location.reload()` as per the comment may not validate all the cached resources:**

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5724282256621568

Answer (score 0):

To send keys to driver you first need to specify the html element you are sending keys to.

```
emailBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath here")
emailBox.send_keys("example@example.com")
```

And repeat for every element.
You can also use the `.click()` function for buttons.

Comment: This was not what the author wants to know

Comment: I understood that already but thanks anyways!